# Querying stream table with multiple source id throws exception

Tags: facebook-fql, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am using FQL query to get update for list of source ids.

```
select type,post_id, message,permalink, created_time,updated_time,type,message_tags, app_data, attachment from stream where source_id IN (page_id1,page_id2)
```

I have used my app access token, also I have added read_stream permission in extended permissions.

I got following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#606) Queries for multiple source_ids require a non-zero viewer that has granted read_stream permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 606
  }
}
```

My app has 10 users.I have check insights of my app,it show Monthly Active Users :10.

Am I missing anything.

Comment: _“I have used my app access token, also I have added read_stream permission in extended permissions.”_ – app access tokens don’t have any permissions; permissions are only applicable to user access tokens.

Comment: Thanks. I have got data for my FQL query with single source id. Also Facebook access token tool(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) gives both app & user access tokens for my app. I have got blank data when I am using user access token.

Comment: I have got problem with multiple source ids.

Comment: Not sure what the exact problem is here. I’d probably just try making it two separate queries (and combining them into one multiquery request).

Comment: Yes that is also applicable. But I have more than 500 page ids.

Comment: did you solve this problem? same happening here. One thing I tried is diving manage_pages permission.

Comment: Did anybody solve this. I run into the same problem: app access token and a query trying to get messages from multiple source_id's. Any help would be appreciate ;)

Comment: I can't even query WHERE source_id = me() :(  I even copy [examples](http://steve.veerman.ca/2012/facebook-api-fql-tutorial/) from tutorials on FQL for reading stream data and they're giving this exception about needing an indexable column.

Comment: Nevermind, my token wasn't valid.  Thanks for the use(less)ful message, FB api.